# Anti-aliased image in IE8/7. What are my options?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-7, antialiasing, jquery-easing

So I'm working on a project for a client and they have an image. They want the image to move at an angle to a certain position on the page. When it does the image becomes jagged and non-anti-aliased in IE7/8. Is there something I'm missing with the jQuery Easing plugin? or is this just an "IE thing"?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
img { -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic; }
```

Comment: Whats the image file type? Does it have transparency? bicubic only works on JPGs and GIFs without transparency.

Comment: If you can get by with a JPG, it may still work, or you chalk it up to "an IE thing".